# two cards next to each other but the Y axe

Tags: html, css

[image: design]

What is an easy way to make these cards look like that? I want the Y axe to be lower for each card. I tried with padding and calc() but it doesn't work

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried for a start.

Comment: There are multiple ways. One way is that you can try selecting successive elements with `nth-child` and then adding `margin-top` to the each consecutive with a CSS variable as the base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nth:child` to select each of them

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.card:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.card:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.card:nth-child(4) {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">2</div>
  <div class="card">3</div>
  <div class="card">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think you need a dynamic approach for aligning these elements.
You can use calc function with inline variable.

With nth child approach you have to mention margin for each and every element and later on if you change your mind and want to update margin than you have to update each and every element once again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .cards {
            vertical-align: top;
        }

            .cards .card {
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align:top;
                height: 150px;
                width: 150px;
                border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
                margin-top: calc(20px * var(--index) );
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cards">
        <div class="card" style="--index:1"></div>
        <div class="card" style="--index:2"></div>
        <div class="card" style="--index:3"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```